# Insert rows within a DataFrame, based on certain conditions

Tags: dataframe, rows

I have a dataframe, 'df' and I want to insert rows based on conditions within df itself. Each 'ID' value must have a corresponding entry for both drinktypes (Beer & Wine). I'd like to say if any ID entry does not have a Beer Type for instance, add row With DrinkType equal to Beer and Drink equal to 'Not Stated'. Similarly, if Beer has been stated for an ID value but not Wine, then add row with Wine under Drink Type and Drink equal to 'Not Stated'. I'd like df to look like df1.

```
df:    

ID    DrinkType    Drink

130   Beer         Fosters
130   Wine         Rose
130   Beer         Budweiser 
102   Beer         Fosters
120   Wine         Pinot Grigot
120   Beer         Budweiser 
99    Wine         Coke
75    Beer         Carling
75    Beer         Fosters


df1:    

ID    DrinkType    Drink

130   Beer         Fosters
130   Wine         Rose
130   Beer         Budweiser 
102   Beer         Fosters
102   Wine         Not Stated
120   Wine         Pinot Grigot
120   Beer         Budweiser 
99    Wine         Coke   
99    Beer         Not Stated
75    Beer         Carling
75    Beer         Fosters
75    Wine         Not Stated
```

Comment: Which library are you using to create df, `pandas`? `pyspark`? What have you tried? What is the issue with your existing code?

Comment: pandas , I just mainly want to know how to insert a new row

Comment: think of loc as a slice operation for extracting data.  Create an empty dataframe and combine slices of data into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Function to insert row in the dataframe at particular index

```
def Insert_row_(row_number, df, row_value): 
     #Slice the upper half of the dataframe 
     df1 = df[0:row_number] 
     # Store the result of lower half of the dataframe 
     df2 = df[row_number:] 

     # Inser the row in the upper half dataframe 
     df1.loc[row_number]=row_value 

     # Concat the two dataframes 
     df_result = pd.concat([df1, df2]) 

     # Reassign the index labels 
     df_result.index = [*range(df_result.shape[0])] 

     # Return the updated dataframe 
     return df_result
```

## Let's create a row which we want to insert

```
index = 2
item_insert = ['Beer','NotStated'] 

if row_number > df.index.max()+1: 
    df[index]=row_value 
else: 
    # Let's call the function and insert the row 
    # at the second position 
    df = Insert_row_(2, df, row_value) 


print(df)
```

## insert any row at last

find max index of current dataframe

```
df[s]=rowvalue or we can use pd.concat(df,df1)
```